# Why can't I see downvote our own posts?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, april-fools

Recently I saw a change on the Stack Overflow website which is I can't see downvote for our own posts. Is this happening for me/everyone? Is this expected behaviour? If yes could someone throw light on this?

[image]
Also today is 1st April. Is Stack Overflow fooling us?

**NOTE:** This is not happening for recent answers. I can't see for my old answers too. I am using Google Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m. I could able to see downvote till yesterday i.e., 31st March 2014.

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? Do you have any particularly weird firewalls? Do you have a down-arrow content filter?

Comment: @Undo: Updated details bro :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the Unicorns took the downvote arrow away... Isn't that a good thing, though? You won't get downvoted anymore.

Comment: I am just curious to know where it went. Its a good thing if Unicorns took the downvote arrow away.. :D :)